# Types of tablet... a tablet secretion

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What would one call a tablet which isn't swallowed?
What verb would be used when taking it?

Would the following phrase be correct?

> To suck the secretion of tablet...

Answer (score 12):

You "suck a *lozenge*" or a *pastille* (British). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lozenge) says

> **lozenge**
>   NOUN
>
> **1.1** A small medicinal tablet, originally in the shape of a lozenge, taken for sore throats and dissolved in the mouth.
>
> *Sucking of lozenges and pastilles produces saliva which lubricates and soothes inflamed tissues and washes infecting organisms off them.*

A **pill** was originally a small, round, solid pharmaceutical oral dosage form of medication. It has become a general term for a medicine taken orally, which can be a tablet, a capsule or a caplet (or when not swallowed, a lozenge). Various types of pill are discussed [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablet_(pharmacy)).

Comment: +1. Might also be worth addressing the other words the OP mentions such as "tablet" and "caplet". I understand "tablet" to mean an elongated-shaped pill which is easier to swallow than a rounded one, and a "caplet" to be a hybrid of *capsule* and *tablet*.

Comment: @Astralbee thanks, I added a little more general information. I think the distinction of "tablet" is not its shape, but that it is a compressed form of a powder, as opposed to capsule and caplet which are shells containing the medicine.

Comment: @Astralbee I believe that it’s a little different.  A tablet was the first compressed form; it is typically **round**. A capsule, as you said, is an elongated shell. A caplet is a compressed pill in the shape of a capsule, but made like a tablet.

Comment: @whiskeychief Yep, I was seeking to clarify all this in an answer of my own but I've deleted it now, I'd rather WeatherVane's answer stand because he's improved it.

Answer (score 3):

**orally disintegrating tablet**

tablets are said to disintegrate in the mouth.

tablets do not "secrete" anything. You suck them and they disintegrate (or dissolve) in the mouth..

secrete means to flow in liquid form.

For example,
The wound was secreting pus. [Sorry, that is gross but shows the point]. That means pus was coming out of the wound.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orally_disintegrating_tablet)

Answer (score 1):

The medical term used in the UK is ***orodispersible.***

[image: picture of a box of orodispersible tablets]

This was first introduced in Europe and is now adopted in the USA as well.

Typically, these are uncoated tablets "dissolve" in the mouth without the need to suck or chew them.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3217286/

Comment: What verb would be used when taking it?

Comment: Worth noting that that is not in common usage in the US. If I heard the word from my doctor, I'd ask for clarification.

Comment: @ColleenV The instructions were visible on the image of the packet, before your made it too small to read :) There isn't a special verb - you just "put it in your mouth" with instructions not to suck of chew it.

Comment: @Karen I was first prescribed this type of tablet when in hospital, so the initial instructions came from the person dispensing them. In fact you wouldn't be tempted to swallow them before they dissolve, because they are too big (about 3/4 inch diameter).

Comment: If there is important text in an image, it should be transcribed so that people using screen readers can benefit from it, and it can be searched. My comment was pointing out that you missed a part of the question.